# How do I normalize/formulate the database design here?

Tags: database, sqlite

I am new to SQL database and I am trying to design a database that will tell the disaster information for the bus affected and bunch other information. Here is my table that I am designing. However, I am not sure whether it is correct or not. Like, I want to know what buses were affected on a particular date based on the disaster information.

So, my entities are disaster, route, and bus

Disaster affects route.

Route affects bus.

[image]

Basically, I would like to figure out which buses were affected in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

The area code/area name information is not normalized: if there are two disasters in the same area, the are name is stored twice; and if there is no disaster in an area, this database does not know its name.

You should have a separate table "Area".

Otherwise, this looks OK: it is possible to determine what buses were affected on a particular date based on this information.

Comment: perhaps, the are can't have multiple disasters